# How to call a method when using AXIOS in v-for Vuejs

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, vue-component

I read a lot of articles and posts and question in StackOverflow and the others but did not get my answer. I'm implementing a simple comment and reply component for my Laravel project.

*** I have a table like below: ***

```
id  |  name  | body              | reply_id | status
---------------------------------------------------------
1   | bran   |   good            |   null   |   accepted
2   | sansa  |  awe full article |   1      |   accepted
3   | jan    | soo Cool          |   1      |   accepted
4   | nightK | dont post it again|   Null   |   accepted
5   | kalici |        wow nice   |   Null   |   accepted
6   | worm   |         why ??    |  4       |   accepted
```

If **reply_id** filed be **Null** i get it as ***main comment*** not as **reply** of comment

in my **vuejs** mounted() i will get all comments that are Null reply_id and accepted by admin from method named by getComments() and call it in mounted() .
also i'm using laravel pagination
my getComments as below vue code :

```
getComments(page = 1) {

        var self = this;
        axios.get('/comment/pagination/+post_id+ '?page=' + page)
            .then(function(response) {
                self.comments = response.data;
            });
```

and show it with blow html and vuejs tags :

```
<div v-for="comment in comments.data" :key="comment.id" class="comments">
    <div class="media comment" v-if="comment.reply==null">
        <img src="/images/avar.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="image">
        <div class="media-body">
                <h6 v-if="comment.user"> {{ comment.user['f_name'] }}  {{ comment.user['l_name'] }} </h6>
                <h6 v-if="!comment.user">{{ comment.name }}</h6>
            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li class="list-inline-item"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>{{ comment.created_at }}</li>
                <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Reply</a></li>
            </ul>
            <p>
                {{ comment.body }}
            </p>

        </div>
    </div>
    <hr>
</div>
```

until here my **component** works well. shows just the main comments.
[image: image of main comments]

now its time to load the replies of main comments . 
i use a method with name **getReplies** :

```
getReplies(MainCommentId) {

    console.log(MainCommentId);
    var self = this;
    axios.get('/comment/replies/' + MainCommentId)
        .then(function(response) {
            console.log(response.data.data);
            self.replies = response.data.data;
        });
},
```

and then i changed my main comment view to below :

```
<div v-for="comment in comments.data" :key="comment.id" class="comments">
                                <div class="media comment">
                                    <img src="/images/avar.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="image">
                                    <div class="media-body">
                                            <h6 v-if="comment.user"> {{ comment.user['f_name'] }}  {{ comment.user['l_name'] }} </h6>
                                            <h6 v-if="!comment.user">{{ comment.name }}</h6>
                                        <ul class="list-inline">
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>{{ comment.created_at }}</li>
                                            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Reply</a></li>
                                        </ul>
                                        <p>
                                            {{ comment.body }}
                                        </p>
                                            <!-- Nested Comment -->
                                            {{  getReplies(comment.id) }}
                                            <div v-for="reply in replies" :key="reply.id" class="media comment">
                                                <img src="/images/avar.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="image">
                                                <div class="media-body">
                                                    <h6 v-if="reply.user"> {{ reply.user['f_name'] }}  {{ reply.user['l_name'] }} </h6>
                                                    <h6 v-if="!reply.user">{{ reply.name }}</h6>
                                                    <ul class="list-inline">
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>{{ reply.created_at }}</li>
                                                        <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Reply</a></li>
                                                    </ul>
                                                    <p>
                                                        {{ reply.body }}
                                                    </p>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <hr>
                            </div>
```

but when it wants to get replies by the method by each step of v-for main comments it will continuously send the request and the change data in HTML reply part. it acts like crazy like the below image.
[image]

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Axios is a promise-based HTTP library, so you have to use it asynchronously. Make the calling function `async getReplies()...` and make axios `await axios.get...`

Comment: @LenJoseph Thanks dude for your answer. but it does not work yet it acts like gif again.

Comment: try changing your `v-if`s to `v-show`s, and call the data methods during `created()` instead of `mounted()`

Comment: @LenJoseph 
 I apply the changes but it is crazy like GIF

Comment: @LenJoseph I think it does not related to mounted because I use
{{  getReplies(comment.id) }} in middle of v-for  to call function to get replies of current main comment

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @LenJoseph  no dude . I have no in my console

Comment: have u figure it out ?

Comment: @Fathy yes i did

Comment: @MohammadaliMirhamed how ? please answer your own question how u have had solved this

Answer (score 0):

This line `{{getReplies(comment.id)}}`   create that issue, `getReplies()` called repeatedly and resetting `replies`

You must preload the `replies` and store it like this

```
 this.replies = {
    '1': [{
            'message': "test"
        },
        {
            'message': "test"
        },
    ],
    '2': [{
            'message': "test"
        },
        {
            'message': "test"
        },
    ]

};
```

The keys`( Now 1 and 2)` of your `replies` array will be main comment id

And  add this function in methods

```
methods : {
        getReply (commentID) {
          return this.replies[commentID];
         }
     }
```

Change the code like this

```
<div v-for="reply in  getReply(comment.id)" :key="reply.id" class="media comment">
    <img src="/images/avar.png" width="50px" height="50px" alt="image">
    <div class="media-body">
        <h6 v-if="reply.user"> {{ reply.user['f_name'] }}  {{ reply.user['l_name'] }} </h6>
        <h6 v-if="!reply.user">{{ reply.name }}</h6>
        <ul class="list-inline">
            <li class="list-inline-item"><span class="fa fa-calendar"></span>{{ reply.created_at }}</li>
            <li class="list-inline-item"><a href="#">Reply</a></li>
        </ul>
        <p>
            {{ reply.body }}
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't want to get all replies of comments by huge JSON in my component.
I need to get my replies by each step of v-for when the main comment is showing